# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in Groovy Script

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, exists, drop-table

Wrote this script:

```
static  void schema()
{
    Sql.newInstance(*DB_CONFIG, DB_DRIVER).execute('''
        drop table if exists post;
        drop table if exists author;
        create table author(
            id integer primary key,
            name varchar(500)
            );
        create table post(
            id integer primary key,
            title varchar(500),
            text longvarchar,
            author integer not nul,
            foreign key(author) references author(id)
            );
        ''')
}
```

and after start, I see this:

> "WARNING: Failed to execute:
>                because: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

I'm using Oracle 11g 2 database and oracle jdbc driver.

Comment: `drop table if exists` is not a valid `Oracle` syntax.

Comment: How need replace this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> drop table if exists post;
>   drop table if exists author;

It is not a valid **Oracle syntax**. You could do it in the following way -

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE post';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;

BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE author';
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
```

There is another syntax error -

> author integer not nul,

Correct it to `NOT NULL`.

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark it as answered if it has helped you.

Comment: Lalit, can you help me again?
I write your answer in script, and after runnig see this:
`ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword`

Comment: The `BEGIN-END` is a PL/SQL block, and the CREATE statements are pure SQL. Make sure you take of the execution of PL/SQL and SQL properly.

Comment: I just started to work with databases. Could you tell me more what you mean?

Comment: Did you fix the other error `NOT NULL`? You had a typo as `NUL`.

Comment: I don't know how to call an Oracle PL/SQL block in Groovy script. Can you please search for the same and try.